# Detect closest face

Tags: python, opencv

Im using the following code to detect face

```
 detections = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
)

for i in range(len(detections)):
        face_i = detections[i]
        gray_i = detections[i]
        x, y, w, h = face_i
```

I wish to detect only the face that is closest to the camera. How can I be able to do so?

Comment: You could assume that the face closest to the camera is the biggest. So select the face with largest h, w or w*h.

Comment: in fact, w and h are the same for OpenCV's face detector, so you can just look at w or h.

Comment: there are multiple w and h values . can  you please provide a short gist on the same?